# Get length of YouTube video from page source?

Tags: php

I noticed that each YouTube video has the following within the page source code:

```
<meta itemprop="duration" content="PT2M22S">
```

How would I get the duration and convert it to seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The duration appears to be formatted according to [ISO 8601 Duration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) so you can use [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) to your advantage here:

```
$p = new DateInterval('PT2M22S');
echo $p->i * 60 + $p->s; // 142
```

The above doesn't include hours, you could add that too using `$p->h * 3600`.